# Current location on road with MapView

Tags: android, google-maps

I made a simple aplication that verifies every 5 secounds the current latitude and longitude of the device, using GPS, through a LocationListener.

I want my aplication to act like a real GPS, I mean, the map will be centered in the device location with a simple marker pointing it, wich I already achived, but on a real-life sittuation when you hold your device in your car, getting lat and loc from both GPS and network service to a better accurary, it might locate you "off-road" and I want the pointer to be on road everytime...

I have searched around but I don't have any idea of what methods to use to achive that, the only thing I tryed was changing the isRouteDisplayed() method of the MapView class to return TRUE, but didn't seem to work.

Comment: The accuracy from GPS should be high enough to place you correctly, i.e. when you are driving on the road your marker will be on the road.

Comment: that means that I don't have to worry if the device for some reason cross throught a zone with less 3G signal for example?
If the logic is well implemented using both GPS and 3G signal or anyother GPRS signal, the marker will be well placed on road everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to take a look to [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.ar/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) on the android documentation that explains how to use Location services correctly.

It even provides the code to know if a new location is "better" than an old one, based on the accuracy, the provider, and the last time the location was updated, so you don't get out of the road when a Network Location update is dispatched right after a gps update.

Comment: I followed up the Android Developer training lessons about LocationManager but didn't see much about this subject.
I'm talking about this lessons: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/locationmanager.html

I will check that article too, never saw that, thanks a lot!